# How to solve the force acting on the box which is in equilibium?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, equilibrium

I did this exercise and it was quite hard, so I decided to come here to ask if my solution is correct. I'm not too sure if my answer was right.

Question:

A man presses horizontally against a box hanging from a rope. The picture shows the situation. The box is assumed to be at rest, so that the rope forms an angle of 30.0° with the vertical direction. Determine the force with which the man acts on the box, if the mass of the box is 25 kg.

[image: The scene]

My solution:

At first I can solve the weight of the box

$G=m\cdot g=25kg\cdot\frac{9.81m}{s^2}=245.25N$

Then I know that the $y$ component of $T$ is

$T_y=-G=-245.25N$

I create a triangle with the vector components, and calculate $T_x$. I assume that the angle between $T_y$ and $T$ is 30 degrees.

Then I solve $T_x$

$\tan \left(30\right)\cdot 245.25N=-1570.91N$

The man acts with $F=-T_x=1570.91N$ on the box

Comment: $\text{tan}(30).(245.25N) = 141.6N$

Comment: Since the box is in equilibrium, do a free body diagram on the box to determine the man's force.

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 1):

$$F = T \sin \theta$$
$$mg = T \cos \theta$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{F}{mg} = \tan \theta$$
$$F = mg \tan \theta$$
here $\theta = 30$ and $m = 25 \ \text{kg}$. So your answer should be about $14.43376 \ g$ which evaluates to about $141.6 \ \text{N}$, if $g$ is taken to be $9.81 \ \text{m/s}^2$.

You have done this incorrectly because you have plugged in the numbers in the calculator without checking whether the angle measurement is set on degrees or radians.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get the right answer, but the following may simplify your calculations,

From free body diagram:
$$F=T\sin\theta$$
$$T\cos\theta = mg$$
Where $F$ is the applied force, $T$ is the tension in the rope and $\theta=30^\circ$

Eliminate $T$ from the above equations, we get
$$F=mg\tan\theta$$